# android widget prompt for unlock

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

I've a problem developing an application, I'm building a Widget that can be either on lockscreen or in home page. when is in lockscreen I want that when the user clicks a button the widget prompt for the user login in case of needed. I mean prompt for patter or password or face recognition depending if the user have any of this security enabled. 
after the user enter his pattern the widget will run an application (intent).

I've notice that some widgets does prompt for login and other doesn't I haven't found the difference between them.

I think this has to be on the onReceive method but not sure how can I call this "login" method, so far on the onReceive I start the intent

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);    
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

but this still not prompt for login. when the widget is on the lockscreen.

let say that the user interacts with the widget in the Lock screen, the user is not prompted to enter the password, either way the user does enter his pattern|password and after the user "enter" his home screen and the application is started.  So the widget does start the intent just don't let the user "know" or login to see the application.

any thoughts on how can I prompt the user to enter his pattern so it enter to the home screen?

[Edit]

The problem occurs when I try to fire the intent within a BroadcastReceiver. 
What I do is allow the user interact with the widgetd buttons, depending on what the user has selected I'll open my application adding some extras to the intent.

so on the onReceive method of my BroadcastReceiver I try to fire:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra(WidgetUtils.TAG_CURRENT_SELECTION, StringIGotFromInteraction);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```

this way the intent don't prompt for the "unblock".

If in the onUpdate I cast the pending intent to any button when the user clicks that button does prompt for the unlock this way:

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.aButton, buildAPendingIntent(context));
```

but I need to know what has the user selected to open and Intent in case I open any.

and my contex.startActivity Approach works fine when the widget is on home screen just not on loockscreen.

Any thoughts how can I make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer what I end up doing was create a dynamic button and when the widget is updated (by the other buttons) I assign the PendingIntent to this button.

So when user clicks this dynamic button the widget attempt to open the intent and is there when the user is prompted for the password.

I think this is not the best solution seance we make the user make an extra click on the widget.